# what does "Timeout exceeded while waiting for event Symbol(NetworkManager.Request)" means?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Upgrading Puppeteer from 19 to 21 and activating the new headless:'new',
i started obtaining this new kind of error

`Timeout exceeded while waiting for event Symbol(NetworkManager.Request)`

that for me is new, i never found neither googling.

this exception is raised in this code block

```
  constructor(opts?: DeferredOptions) {
    this.#timeoutId =
      opts && opts.timeout > 0
        ? setTimeout(() => {
            this.reject(new TimeoutError(opts.message));
          }, opts.timeout)
        : undefined;
  }
```

of this file

```
node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/util/Deferred.ts
```

but i have no idea who or why is raising because i can't have access to the stacktrace while reaching this exception.

the testsuite codebase is the same, from a lot of time, without changes.
the only changes was changing from headless:true to headless:'new'
i was expeting the same behaviour.
i'm trying to keep puppeteer updated.

Any suggestion?

thanks